# tortoiseSVN not installing in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2013, tortoisesvn

i want to add the tortoise in Visual Studio 2013. but i did't find any solution .is there any one who help me to shortcut this trouble?

i try to install latest version of it but the option for 2013 is disable.

Comment: You know this page: http://tortoisesvn.net/visualstudio.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) allows you to use TortoiseSVN from Visual Studio IDE. There is also [AnkhSVN](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) but it has its "own" interface, it's unrelated to TortoiseSVN.

See [How to integrate TortoiseSVN into Visual Studio](http://tortoisesvn.net/visualstudio.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer but i want visualSVN for visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 integration plugins for SVN to Visual Studio that I know of.

- [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) is one. Its good.
- [AnkhSVN](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/downloads) is also good.